# Update model property in Asp.net mvc kendo ui async file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a kendo ui async file upload with the following options on my view.

```
<div class="demo-section">
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("Save", "Upload")
            .AutoUpload(true)
        )
    )
</div>
```

In the corresponding action method  ,I would like to set my model's properties for filename .Shown below is what i have currently .

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                // We are only interested in the file name.
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

                // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                // file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
            }
        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

If there is a way to do it ,please let me know ..

Comment: This question is not clear. What model?

Comment: I am referring to the model class which has strong binding to the view

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{

    var savedFilePaths = new List<string>();
    var applicationPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Content/Images/Others/";

    // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Some browsers send file names with full path.
            // We are only interested in the file name.
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            if (fileName != null)
            {
                 fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddmm-") + fileName;
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Hotel"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                savedFilePaths.Add(applicationPath + fileName);
            }

        }
    }

    // Return an empty string to signify success
    return Content("");
}
```